# @import X; Causes error Could not build module X

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, module

I have a custom framework TSUI defined as a module. It has both Objective-C and Swift code. If I import it in Objective-C code as follows:

```
#import <TSUI/TSUI.h>
```

Everything works just fine, but then I get only access to the Objective-C code. However, if I import it as:

```
@import TSUI;
```

or

```
#import <TSUI/TSUI.h>
#import <TSUI/TSUI-Swift.h>
```

Everything compiles fine, but in Xcode I get the following error:
[image]

In both the framework and the app code I've set the following build settings:

- Embedded content contains Swift code = YES
- Allow Non-Modular Includes In Framework Modules = YES
- Enable Modules = YES

I've tried cleaning the project, cleaning the derived data, and the issue keeps coming back. It also appears if the framework contains no Swift code but is included with @import instead of #import. At the moment I would consider it to be a bug.

Comment: have you tried building the project before importing it?

Comment: Can you create and upload a small sample project with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your current import statements
so the project compiles.

Build your project.

Try and import again.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your module. I believe in your TSUI project you need to set a modulemap file. You should have a file that just imports all of the files you would like to include in the module. You can call it TSUI-umbrella.h. In your modulemap you should set this as your umbrella header. Then when you run @import (which imports the module) you will get a proper compilation. Additionally you can do

```
#import <TSUI/TSUI-umbrella.h>
```

or basically

```
#import <ModuleName/UmbrellaHeader>
```